# How to Autoplay Music and stop/resume with Spacebar?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

so i wanted to add Music to my Website but at start the Music isn´t playing. To make it play I have to press my spacebar. But actually it shoul play on start and you can pause and resume the musik by pressing Spacebar? Does anyone know a solution?

```
    <div id="audio">
        <audio controls loop autoplay hidden>
        <!-- Audio is looped, plays automatically and is hidden -->
            <source src="music/music.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>
    </div>
    <script>
        var audio = new Audio('music/music.ogg');
        audio.volume = 0.05;
        audio.play();
        if (audio) {

  window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {

    var key = event.which || event.keyCode;

    if (key === 32) { // spacebar

      // eat the spacebar, so it does not scroll the page
      event.preventDefault();

      audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause();

    }

  });
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you need to put the music playing part into an event handler
i.e: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Sometimes it could be that browser prevents musics/audio to be autoplayed also